# How can a generic resource be overallocated?

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning

MS Project.

My understanding is that a generic resource is specifically of infinite availability. That's why it's generic.

So in the very early stages of our journey to implementing resource management, we are starting by simply assigning ONLY generic resources to see what sort of demand there is.

Now I have a generic resource who is "over allocated". How is that possible?

I've tried making the max availability 999% and 0% thinking maybe that will some secret key to making it behave as I believe it should.

Naturally I can make it a COST resource rather than a WORK resource, then actual allocation is by assignment count rather than hours, but I'm still surprised by the behaviour.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Setting Max Units to a large number should do the trick. FYI 999% = 9.99 units. Try setting max units to 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS Project doesn't know a generic resource from a non-generic resource. To Project, it's just a resource name.

If you are intending for your resources to be generic and do not want to show them ever overallocated, just change the *Max Units* field on the resource on the resource sheet to a large number, like 100,000%

Example:

from this:
[image: Overallocated Resource]

to this:
[image]